# Windows 10 Desktop Context Menu Won't Open

Tags: windows, windows-10, context-menu, right-click

When my PC first starts up, I am able to select and open anything on my desktop. However, when I right click on my desktop, my mouse becomes the loading circle, and the context menu never appears. I also can't open any folders or applications on my desktop, but right clicking and opening files/folders works everywhere else, including the taskbar and Windows Explorer.

Comment: I can't reproduce this problem on my Windows 10 PC (and I doubt that many others can either). There must be something unique about your PC that is causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The most simples method, system reset, keep my files.

In my opinion, I suspect that you have some third-party software startup with system, open task manager\Startup tab to disable unnecessary software.

Another possibility, user profile issue, create a new account and boot in to this account, test Content menu.